# Невозможно преобразовать QByteArray в QJsonDocument

Tags: json, qt, парсер

В общем, проблема в следующем. Мне надо из Qt прочитать json файл из директории \data_sportsmens. Файл открывается, все считывается, а вот при попытке запихнуть все это в QJsonDocument фейл. Не могу понять в чем проблема, чек на пустоту выдает true.

```
QFile fin(":/data_sportsmens/NoNameSportsmen.json");
fin.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(fin.readAll());
fin.close();
qDebug() << doc.isEmpty();
```

Нужна помощь, срочно, буду благодарен за любую инфу по этой проблеме (возможно просто взгляд замылен и я не вижу очевидного)

Comment: а сам json точно валидный?

Comment: Да, json валидный, однако есть с ним другая проблема. Прога открывает файл только если указать абсолютный путь к нему, по относительному просто не видит от слова совсем

Comment: Пора познакомится с тем, что такое рабочий каталог, и почему он не всегда совпадает с тем каталогом, в котором находиться бинарник

Comment: Но при этом другие файлы, находящиеся во вложенных папках текущей директории читаются без проблем, а вот с этим файлом именно запара

Comment: Двоеточие - это ресурс, а не реальный файл.

Comment: я знаю, сам же писал. Не видит ни в ресах ни просто в папке. Нашел такой косяк - все норм читается и парсится из класса основного окна (mainwindow) но при попытке вынести это в отдельный класс и в статический метод этого класса ловлю такой баг